# Service started from widget doesn't work in Oreo

Tags: android, widget

When I implemented my widget a couple years ago, I used this advice from the App Widgets page on the development site (still there):  "If your App Widget setup process can take several seconds (perhaps while performing web requests) and you require that your process continues, consider starting a Service in the onUpdate() method." I did this and it worked like a charm when built for SDKs up through 25.

It also worked on Android 8.0, but as soon as I targeted 26, the app started crashing in the onUpdate method of the widget provider when issuing the startService call. The error message had to do with trying to start a background service from another background service, and although I tried a few things in the service definition in the manifest I couldn't get it working.

I ended up doing a workaround when I decided that I didn't really need to update the widget from a service, so now just do the update directly in onUpdate. Services and background/foreground issues are something I've not messed with much, but I'd still like to know if there is a way to have kept using a service to update the widget.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in Android O, we have a new background limitations. When you're trying to startService(), you will get IlleagalStateException, so now you should use startForegroundService(), but if you start service by this new method, you will get RemoteServiceException. To avoid this exception you have 5 seconds to make startForeground() after startForegroundService(), to notify user, that you're working in background.

So, where is only one way in Android O:

```
context.startForegroundService(intent)
```

And in service onCreate() make something like that:

```
startForeground(1, new Notification());
```

**UPDATE**
So as i assume, some manufacturers have backport on Android N these new background limitations, that's why you can get same exception in Android N.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what was happening, and I didn't manage to find a solution (I was not aware of the startForegroundService call).

Comment: Does it work also for Samsung devices? It seems Samsung is killing background processes if the device is "optimizing battery"? Any solution to that? Ref: dontkillmyapp.com/samsung

Answer (score 2):

Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it is difficult to help you. Depending on what you had, you could have:

- Switched to `JobIntentService`, particularly if your old service was an `IntentService` and you did not mind the possibility of a several-second delay in the work being started
- Called `startForegroundService()` on `Context` (instead of `startService()`) to start your service, and in your service call `startForeground()`, to make your service be a foreground service
- Called `getForegroundService()` on `PendingIntent` (instead of `getService()`),  and in your service call `startForeground()`, to make your service be a foreground service

Comment: for JobIntentService what do you think about Samsung killing background processes if the device is "optimizing battery" or in "power optimization" mode? Any solution to that? Ref: https://dontkillmyapp.com/samsung

Comment: @agirardello: That should not be a direct problem here, insofar as the scenario is that the user taps on an app widget. That implies that the screen is on and the user is interacting with the device. What I think *can* be a problem with some of this aggressive power management is wiping out `PendingIntents` (courtesy of "force stop"-style behavior). That would affect the app widget, but it would not be unique to using `JobIntentService`.

Comment: as you mentioned, tapping a widget brings the app to foreground (via an Activity) and the JobIntentService is finally triggered, however on boot this does not happen (unless you click of course...) and widgets show their default "loading state" as they need the service to calculate something (in my case, is a countdown widget). I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63111658/jobintentservice-onhandlework-is-not-always-called and gonna try if it's working, even if the annoying notification will be shown for short time; I just don't find the UX that "clean" for my use case

Comment: maybe Widgets should also be considered as "foreground"? O_o

Comment: @agirardello: "and widgets show their default "loading state" as they need the service to calculate something" -- the `AppWidgetProvider` should be being called with `onUpdate()` when it is being put onto the home screen following a reboot. `onUpdate()` could trigger a `JobIntentService` or `WorkManager` or something to get the work done. "maybe Widgets should also be considered as "foreground"?" -- they are for some things.

Comment: did exactly that: on boot is correctly called AppWidgetProvider .onUpdate() but, on a real Samsung device with "battery optimization" on (which is default for a user) it prevents to execute JobIntentService.onHandleWork(). I also thought about WorkManager, but doesn't it have side effects with widgets? https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/01/15/workmanager-side-effects-follow-up.html

Comment: @agirardello: "I also thought about WorkManager, but doesn't it have side effects with widgets?" -- you would need to take special care to not blindly schedule work in `onUpdate()`. Plus, if `JobIntentService` is not working, my guess is that `WorkManager` will not be much better, insofar as both rely on `JobScheduler`, and that is what Samsung is fouling up. I am surprised that the effects are seen on a reboot, though. Frankly, I don't know what to recommend.

Comment: Still in the context of Samsung devices and "battery optimization", I discovered the following: AppWidgetProvider. onUpdate() -> JobIntentService.enqueueWork() -> does NOT call JobIntentService.onHandleWork(). However, AppWidgetProvider. onUpdate() -> AlarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() -> BroadcastReceiver -> JobIntentService.enqueueWork() -> calls without problem JobIntentService.onHandleWork()

Comment: @agirardello The way with BroadcastReceiver seems like works for me. But why not use WorkManager from the BroadcastReceiver? Will it produce the side effects in the case?

Comment: I did some tests today with AppWidgetProvider. onUpdate() (and onAppWidgetOptionsChanged()) -> AlarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() -> BroadcastReceiver -> WorkManager.OneTimeWorkRequest and I dont see the side effects with androidx.work:work-runtime:2.4.0

Comment: @Alex I ended up completely skipping JobIntentService or WorkManager, and rather run my code (it's just a few offline checks and use of NotificationManager) inside a Thread in the BroadcastReceiver by calling goAsync() as suggested here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html In this way it seems fully back-compatible with old devices, but also passing the "background" restrictions of certain device manufacturers on new OS versions (as mentioned in my previous comments)